# AWS S3 SDK for Ruby 'multipart copy'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm looking for the Ruby component to this part of the SDK (Multipart Copy Part)

I can't find references to it on the latest ruby aws-sdk.

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html

The thing is I can't seem to find it, Is the SDK comprehensive or would I have to write this part manually? How would I go about making a restful request?

Answer (score 0):

I know this cames so late... but I've found your question, so others may find it as well.

In version 3 of the API you can find the  documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/MultipartUpload.html